# Module pyfiglet not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code :

```
import pyfiglet

print(dir(pyfiglet))
```

The error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet'
```

---

Even though I downloaded "pip 21.0.1" and imported it, it does the same thing to "termcolor" package.

Comment: Make sure you have run "pip install pyfiglet" first. After that, make sure you import it using the correct version of python. some modules can be imported in the 32 bit version but give an error when imported from the 64 bit version.

Comment: & How To Make Sure Of The Type Of My Python ( 32 - 64 ) ?
 - Sorry I Don't Get It ?

Comment: Try and run your code from the python IDLE by right clicking your python file and choosing "edit with idle" and the choosing either the 32 or the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i install pip and the command

pip install pifiglet

report this results
equirement already satisfied: pyfiglet in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (0.8.post1)

but if i do the original command i have this response
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
ImportError: cannot import name 'figlet_format' from 'pyfiglet' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyfiglet/**init**.py)

but in this path there is the file...

Answer (score 0):

Before you can import a library, it needs to already be on your drive. You are importing it into your file. In order to get it onto your drive in the first place, you have to install it.

From the command prompt, type:

```
pip install pifiglet
```

Once you've done that, you should be able to import it.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedF.Al-Sorougy please be polite, you have not mentioned it, so this is a reasonable attempt to help you. Please update your question so others will be aware that you have already done that.

Comment: Alright, despite i have said that before.. Do u know the answer plz??